# JSPWiki/Tomcat — several JNDIReamls per webapp

Tags: tomcat, jndi, jdbcrealm

I am running a JSPWiki with a JNDIRealm for Authentication against an Active Directory.

Now I have to think about the possibility to add another JNDIRealm to give access to users from another domain controller.

I have seen many solutions to define Realms per webapp/context/engine but no statement, if I can define two different JNDIReamls per webapp.

If it is possible, will there be an error, if a user exists in both domains?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#CombinedRealm for a solution :-)

Comment: Please sum up or quote the crucial bits here. Link rot happens. Thanks.